# How to make menubar cut/copy/paste with Python/Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to make menu items (in the menubar, not in a right click pop-up window) that can cut/copy/paste whatever text is selected.

*The equivalent keyboard commands already work without my having done anything to enable them*. For example, I can enter text in an entry box, cut it with Control-X, and paste it back (or elsewhere) with Control-C.

The posts on the topic I've seen boil down to cut/copy/paste for individual widgets, but that already works. How do I make the menu items activate them?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Just to be clear, The issues are:

- how to make the menu items for cut/copy act on whatever text is selected in any widget
- how to have the paste menu item paste text wherever the text cursor is

Again, the key commands to do this (Control-x, Control-c, Control-v) already work without my having done anything. *I know how to make the menus*; the question is just what command I should attach to the menu items to have the desired effect.

EDIT 2:
Ok, I've got a way that works. Since the key commands already work, we can just generate them. In my case, everything is a a notebook named noteBook so

`lambda: self.noteBook.event_generate('<Control-x>')`

cuts as desired. For example:

`editmenu.add_command(label="Cut", accelerator="Ctrl+X", command=lambda: self.noteBook.event_generate('<Control-x>'))`

In use: https://github.com/lnmaurer/qubit-control-interface/commit/c08c10a7fbc4a637c1e08358fb9a8593dfdf116e

**Still, there's probably a cleaner way to do this; please reply if you know it.**

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=JnR9hQA3SncC&pg=PA426&lpg=PA426&dq=how-to-make-menubar-cut-copy-paste-with-python-tkinter&source=bl&ots=Jb3UIuV57w&sig=jhxfhQ4hGbOS9-HIkcdvFayhj_o&hl=en&ei=2EDiTsWLKNGbtwf78PyHBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=how-to-make-menubar-cut-copy-paste-with-python-tkinter&f=false

Comment: John, as the text states, all that code does is print things to stdout for demonstration purposes. It does not address my question.

Comment: Where? I searched for the word 'paste' (using the little entry area to the left) and it occurs 4 times. None of them address my question. The same goes for 'cut'. I'll believe that the information I'm looking for is in there if you point out the page; it certainly wasn't on the page you linked to.

Comment: http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkclipboard.html pyGTK has a clipboard feature, might be worth looking into.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato: how does a function in pyGTK help someone who is using Tkinter? Or are you suggesting they rewrite their whole app in another toolkit?

Answer (score 14):

try this: [source](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/156826-cut-paste-text-between-tkinter-widgets)

```
import Tkinter

def make_menu(w):
    global the_menu
    the_menu = Tkinter.Menu(w, tearoff=0)
    the_menu.add_command(label="Cut")
    the_menu.add_command(label="Copy")
    the_menu.add_command(label="Paste")

def show_menu(e):
    w = e.widget
    the_menu.entryconfigure("Cut",
    command=lambda: w.event_generate("<<Cut>>"))
    the_menu.entryconfigure("Copy",
    command=lambda: w.event_generate("<<Copy>>"))
    the_menu.entryconfigure("Paste",
    command=lambda: w.event_generate("<<Paste>>"))
    the_menu.tk.call("tk_popup", the_menu, e.x_root, e.y_root)

t = Tkinter.Tk()
make_menu(t)

e1 = Tkinter.Entry(); e1.pack()
e2 = Tkinter.Entry(); e2.pack()
e1.bind_class("Entry", "<Button-3><ButtonRelease-3>", show_menu)

t.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, @JohnRiselvato - great example (used it [here](http://sdaaubckp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sdaaubckp/xtra/youtube-dl-gui-tkdnd/youtube-dl-gui-tkdnd.py?view=markup)); cheers!

Answer (score 8):

Use the `focus_get()` method to get the widget which currently has keyboard focus, and then send the event to that widget. E.g.

```
editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
editmenu.add_command(label="Cut", \
                     accelerator="Ctrl+X", \
                     command=lambda: \
                             mywindow.focus_get().event_generate('<<Cut>>'))
```

Comment: Is this meaningfully different from the code I posted in EDIT 2?

Comment: Your code in edit 2 generates a <Control-X> event. You asked for a cleaner way to do it. This code generates a <<Cut>> event and sends it to whatever widget has keyboard focus. So yes, it is meaningfully different and cleaner IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Have Fun

```
from Tkinter import *

class Test(Text):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        Text.__init__(self, master, **kw)
        self.bind('<Control-c>', self.copy)
        self.bind('<Control-x>', self.cut)
        self.bind('<Control-v>', self.paste)

    def copy(self, event=None):
        self.clipboard_clear()
        text = self.get("sel.first", "sel.last")
        self.clipboard_append(text)

    def cut(self, event):
        self.copy()
        self.delete("sel.first", "sel.last")

    def paste(self, event):
        text = self.selection_get(selection='CLIPBOARD')
        self.insert('insert', text)

def test():
    r = Tk()
    t = Test(r)
    t.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
    r.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: It looks like what you're doing is binding key key commands to actions for a widget. As I stated, that already works without my having done anything. The question is how to make the menu items for cut/copy act on whatever text is selected in any widget and how to have the paste menu item paste text wherever the text cursor is

Comment: @BryanOakley - yes, he deserves punishment for that (irony off)

Answer (score 0):

I just came across your question nine months too late (does that make this a pregnant pause?).  This code works for me:

```
    editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    editmenu.add_command(label="Cut", \
                         accelerator="Ctrl+X", \
                         command=lambda: \
                                 self.editor.event_generate('<<Cut>>'))
    editmenu.add_command(label="Copy", \
                         accelerator="Ctrl+C", \
                         command=lambda: \
                                 self.editor.event_generate('<<Copy>>'))
    editmenu.add_command(label="Paste", \
                         accelerator="Ctrl+V", \
                         command=lambda: \
                                 self.editor.event_generate('<<Paste>>'))
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question being asked -- the question talks about having cut/copy/paste work for any widget. All you've done is tied the cut/copy/paste actions to a single widget.