# How do I enable right click in entry and output widget for pasting and copying respectively in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm still working on the translator app, with the help of Python Dictionary. But I have this challenge: I want to be able to right click in the entry widget and paste keys as well as right click in the output widget and copy values. I'm only able to do so with keyboard shortcut; for convenience sake, I want to be able to do so with the mouse. Thanks. Below is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter. messagebox
root=Tk()
root.geometry('250x250')
root.title("Meta' Translator")
root.configure(background="#35424a")
from playsound import playsound

#Entry widget object
textin = StringVar()

#press ENTER key to activate translate button
def returnPressed(event):
  clk()

def clk():
    entered = ent.get().lower() #get user input and convert to lowercase
    output.delete(0.0,END)
    if len(entered) > 0:
        try:
            textin = exlist[entered]
        except:
            textin = 'Word not found'
        output.insert(0.0,textin)

def play():
    text = output.get("0.0", "end").strip("\n")
    if text == "əsɔ́":
        playsound("hoe.mp3")
    elif text == "jam":
        playsound("axe.mp3")
    elif text == "ɨghə́":
        playsound("eye.mp3")
    else:
        # If there is no sound file for the translation:
        playsound("eze.mp3")

#heading
lab0=Label(root,text='Translate English Words to Meta\'',bg="#35424a",fg="silver",font= 
('none 11 bold'))
lab0.place(x=0,y=2)

#Entry field
ent=Entry(root,width=15,font=('Times 18'),textvar=textin,bg='white')
ent.place(x=30,y=30)

#focus on entry widget
ent.focus()

#Search button
but=Button(root,padx=1,pady=1,text='Translate',command=clk,bg='powder blue',font=('none 18 
bold'))
but.place(x=60,y=90)

#press ENTER key to activate Translate button
root.bind('<Return>', returnPressed)

#output field
output=Text(root,width=15,height=1,font=('Times 18'),fg="black")
output.place(x=30,y=170)

#play button
play_button=Button(root,padx=1,pady=1,text='Play',command=play,bg='powder blue',font=('none 
10 bold'))
play_button.place(x=100,y=210)

#prevent sizing of window
root.resizable(False,False) 

#Dictionary
exlist={
    "hat":"ɨ̀də̀m", 
    "hoe":"əsɔ́",
    "honey":"jú",
    "chest":"ɨgɔ̂",
    "eye":"ɨghə́",
    "ear":"ǝ̀tǒŋ",
    "axe":"jam"

    }

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8476726/12198502)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code has a lot of dependency, it cannot be run on another system, so here is a common example which you should be able to implement to your code easily:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def popup(event):
    try:
        menu.tk_popup(event.x_root,event.y_root) # Pop the menu up in the given coordinates
    finally:
        menu.grab_release() # Release it once an option is selected

def paste():
    clipboard = root.clipboard_get() # Get the copied item from system clipboard
    e.insert('end',clipboard) # Insert the item into the entry widget

def copy():
    inp = e.get() # Get the text inside entry widget
    root.clipboard_clear() # Clear the tkinter clipboard
    root.clipboard_append(inp) # Append to system clipboard

menu = Menu(root,tearoff=0) # Create a menu
menu.add_command(label='Copy',command=copy) # Create labels and commands
menu.add_command(label='Paste',command=paste)

e = Entry(root) # Create an entry
e.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

e.bind('<Button-3>',popup) # Bind a func to right click

root.mainloop()
```

I have explained it with comments to understand on-the-go, nothing complicated. The menu just pops up when you right click on the entry as the function is binded to the entry alone. I think, without `clipboard_clear()` it would append all the items in the tkinter clipboard to the system clipboard.

Comment: I did some modification on ur code: I enabled paste only in the entry widget and copy only in the output widget. Thanks for the contribution.

Comment: @DieudonneTambah  ~ Would appreciate marking this as the correct answer if this answered your questions correctly. Click [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/775796) to learn how :D

Comment: How do I mark it as the correct answer? Can't figure it out yet

Comment: I got it. Done. Need to do same for the others before